# Access the variables of a class in another class

Tags: robotium

I seek to know that can we create an object of one test class in another test class and acess the variables:

Ex: A string value of a textView which is assigned to a variable in class A.
    Can we access the variable by creating the object of the class A in Class B!!

Plz Help!!

Answer (score 2):

It's not good and clean solution to create instance of test class inside another test class. I recommend you to create another class to keep those values, if you really need it. However your test classes should be independent.

Answer (score 1):

For eg. if you are having two class file between which the variable to be shared Consider,

`classA.java
 classB.java`

create a New class called `AppConstants.java` with variables type as,

`public static view variableDeclaration =(view).....`

With this common variable in `AppConstants` file can be shared between any number of class files